# How to write a long type into bytesarray

Tags: java, python, netty

i have a socket server that written by java(using netty),i use  LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder to decode message ; the encoder ,if use java should 
be:

```
Message.Type msgType = in.type();
// All messages have the frame length, message type, and message itself.
int headerLength = 8 + msgType.encodedLength() + in.encodedLength();
// long frameLength = headerLength + bodyLength;
ByteBuf header = ctx.alloc().heapBuffer(headerLength);
//header.writeLong(frameLength);
header.writeLong(headerLength);

msgType.encode(header);
in.encode(header);
```

but now i need a socket client written by python ,so how do i write the message length(8 bytes,long type) into buffer

Comment: Did you try ByteBuffer.toArray()?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to bit-shift stuff. I am not a python programmer so I am not sure about the python syntax but basically this is how its implemented in java:

```
static void setLong(byte[] memory, int index, long value) {
    memory[index]     = (byte) (value >>> 56);
    memory[index + 1] = (byte) (value >>> 48);
    memory[index + 2] = (byte) (value >>> 40);
    memory[index + 3] = (byte) (value >>> 32);
    memory[index + 4] = (byte) (value >>> 24);
    memory[index + 5] = (byte) (value >>> 16);
    memory[index + 6] = (byte) (value >>> 8);
    memory[index + 7] = (byte) value;
}
```

So just do the same shifting in python and you should be fine. BTW this is `BIG_ENDIAN` encoding.

Comment: i have solved this problem ,the way just like you say, the code that i follow :java.nio.Bits.java:369 .

Answer (score 0):

A socket client allows you to read byte by byte.

Read 8 bytes, get a byte string:

```
bytes_sequence = client_socket.read(8)
```

Note that each element of `bytes_sequence` is a "character", so you need to use `ord()` to get its numeric value.

Now convert it into a 8-byte `long` if you need.

For big-endian data ("network order"), you can

```
def from_big_endian(bytes_sequence):
  result = 0
  for b in bytes_sequence:
    result = result << 8 + ord(b)  # ord() converts b to integer.
  return result
```

Or, shorter:  `reduce(lambda acc, v: (acc << 8) + ord(v), bytes_sequence, 0)`.

For little-endian sequence, you can e.g. reverse the byte sequence, and handle it as a big-endian sequence:

```
big_endian_seq = little_endian_seq[::-1]
```

Or you can write an explicit loop for combining it into an integer like above.

Comment: xie xie a lot,it is a late prefect answer , im a newer in python ,so i use a unskillful method solved this by follow jdk source code,this part of my code  def long7(x):
    b= struct.pack('>I', x >> 56)
    return b[len(b)-1]


def long6(x):
    b= struct.pack('>I', x >> 48)
    return b[len(b)-1]